# Magento 2.4.5+ Product Page Vimeo Videos - Attention Error: Video not found

Tags: magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6, vimeo

I have seen this was an old problem where if you try to add a Vimeo video to the product page a modal appears with Attention Error: "Video not found". According to Adobe this was fixed from 2.4.3, but I have tried 2.4.5-p1 and 2.4.6 and I get the same error.

I already have Vimeo added to my CSP policies and have tried adding `player.vimeo.com` to the `*.vimeo.com` which already exists.

Currently all the product videos that were added in the past work. But, if I click on them now the URL is blank with the error, even though the database contains the correct URLs. Trying to add a new URL gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I managed to fix this by adding an extra policy `<value id="vimeo" type="host">vimeo.com</value>` without the wildcard to `script-src` and `frame-src`.